# App Icons Duplicated in Asset Catalog and Root Bundle Directory

Tags: ios

I notice that when I use an asset catalog to specify my iOS app's icon, the resulting app has both an Assets.car file with the icons in it, as well as the individual icon files in the root bundle directory.

The app has iOS 9 as its deployment target.

I'm checking the resulting bundle by archiving the project and exporting it (via Xcode's Organizer window) as an Ad Hoc build with the App Thinning option set to iPhone 6s.  This is on Xcode 9.3.1.

When I [inspect](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer) the Assets.car file in the thinned app, I see that it only has the size 40, 58, 80, 114, and 120 icons (as well as a 200x178 image that the [asset catalog viewer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer) calls ZZZZPackedAsset-2.0 which contains 4 versions of the icon embedded in it which I've measured to be sizes: 42, 60, 82, and 116).

The icon files in the root bundle directory are the following:

- AppIcon20x20@2x.png
- AppIcon20x20@2x~ipad.png
- AppIcon20x20@3x.png
- AppIcon20x20~ipad.png
- AppIcon29x29.png
- AppIcon29x29@2x.png
- AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
- AppIcon29x29@3x.png
- AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
- AppIcon40x40@2x.png
- AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
- AppIcon40x40@3x.png
- AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
- AppIcon50x50@2x~ipad.png
- AppIcon50x50~ipad.png
- AppIcon57x57.png
- AppIcon57x57@2x.png
- AppIcon60x60@2x.png
- AppIcon60x60@3x.png
- AppIcon72x72@2x~ipad.png
- AppIcon72x72~ipad.png
- AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
- AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
- AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x~ipad.png

So I have two questions:

1. Why are icon assets duplicated as external AppIcon*.png files and internal Assets.car assets?
2. Why do the individual AppIcon*.png include all of the icons and not just the ones need?

I was under the impression that iOS 9+ can use the asset catalog for its icon assets.  Is this just a discrepancy in the bundle that Xcode produces versus what will happen on the app store?  Or is it an incorrect assumption that I'm making about how the app thinning app export option works?

Comment: This post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665987/opt-into-app-thinning-for-icons-in-asset-catalog-in-existing-project seems to indicate that there may be a way to have app icons participate in app thinning.  However, I can't find any information on the subject aside from the brief mention in the wwdc video.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the app icons, the asset catalog is a human labor-saving device, not a space-saving device.

Historically, there were not always asset catalogs; instead, the iOS system on the device expects to find the app icons at the top level of the app bundle, with highly specific names derived from a name specified in the *Info.plist*.

You could configure that yourself, and that's what we used to have to do.

But to save you the trouble of worrying about that, you are offered the option to put the app icons in the asset catalog instead — and then the app-building process does for you what you would previously have done yourself, writing the icons out to the top level of the app bundle and modifying the *Info.plist* to point to them.

Comment: Yes, I used to specify the icons myself.  What's bothering me is that it seems that specifying the icons in the asset catalog results in a bigger app size because the icons are now stored in two separate places within the app.

Comment: Then don't use the asset catalog for the icons, if that really bothers you.

Comment: The thing is, I like the idea of app thinning only including the necessary icons.  This is the reason I switched to the asset catalog.  However, it seems to defeat the purpose in this case where the icons are duplicated.  I'm just wondering if this is really how the app is delivered to the end-user, or if it's just an incorrect simulation by the app thinning Xcode export option.

Comment: Shame on Apple. It's appalingly wasteful to include the icon assets twice! Some Mac app bundles have dozens of icons, each of them containing various representations that can be up to 1024x1024 in size. In such cases, we could be talking about dozens of additional megabytes.